# create DataSet<Row> from Dataset created reading from a socket (Spark Java)

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, streaming

In Spark Streaming when the input source is a csv file and I read it through a socket (Java), a `Dataset<Row>` is created with only a `string` column and the value of each row contains each line sent through the socket.

When I know the format of each line, e.g. the first two values of the csv line are `Strings` the next is an `integer` and so on, is t possible to declare my schema and create another `Dataset<Row>` based on that schema and place the data accordingly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,if it is csv i dont see any point to use spark streaming for that.It will be hisotrical data ,data is not changing.So you should use spark sql only to read and process csv.

You can create your schema by crating StructField and decalre data types.

Comment: This is true for production. However tutorials on streaming are often simplified by working with some static files. It easier to learn the api like this

Comment: You are right but I want to implement it for a project, it is for learning purposes. So i would like to know if what I asked is possible.